# Calculate the difference in dates based on the entries in another column

Tags: r, date

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-05 |
| 1 | 2022-09-07 |
| 1 | 2022-09-10 |
| 2 | 2022-09-16 |
| 2 | 2022-09-07 |

1. The ID's are not unique.
2. In the case where the ID appears more than twice then get the average of days (i.e for ID = 1 , the outcome will be  `mean(c(difftime(2022-09-10,2022-09-07,units="days"),mean(c(difftime(2022-09-07,2022-09-05,units="days")))`)
3. In the case where the ID has only 2 entries the just get the difference between the dates

The desired outcome for the above table should be

| ID | Days |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 days |
| 2 | 9 days |

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```r
aggregate(Date ~ ID, df, \(x) mean(abs(diff(x))))

  ID     Date
1  1 2.5 days
2  2 9.0 days
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, ID) %>%
  summarise(res=mean(difftime(Date, lag(Date), units="days"), na.rm=TRUE))
```

---

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     ID res      
  <dbl> <drtn>   
1     1  2.5 days
2     2 -9.0 days
```

---

Data

```
df <- tibble(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2),
             Date=c(as.Date("2022-09-05"),
                    as.Date("2022-09-07"),
                    as.Date("2022-09-10"),
                    as.Date("2022-09-16"),
                    as.Date("2022-09-07")))
```